# Python and c # real-time communication

Tags: python, c#, database

I have two programs, in python and c#. Python is constantly checking the data, and c # should output that data in the interface. I need this to happen in real time.
I was advised to configure the launch of a local server for data exchange, but isn't there an easier way?

Comment: How heavy is the process of the Python script?

Comment: _"I need this to happen in real time."_ - You need a real time system, then.

Comment: ^^ But fun aside, I guess you don't actually mean "real time" but "as fast as possible". In that case: I'd consider and investigate IronPython, ZeroMQ (or some other MessageQueue to your preference), or some DB that can act as a message queue like Redis.

Comment: *"constantly checking the data"* - sounds like you need IPC, e.g named pipes. [Here](https://www.eadan.net/blog/ipc-with-named-pipes/) some tutorial for python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is it working now? Are you getting the result from the Python file inside the C# script? E.g like the below [snippet](https://betterprogramming.pub/running-python-script-from-c-and-working-with-the-results-843e68d230e5)?

```
    public string run_cmd(string cmd, string args)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
        start.FileName = "PATH_TO_PYTHON_EXE";
        start.Arguments = string.Format("\"{0}\" \"{1}\"", cmd, args);
        start.UseShellExecute = false;// Do not use OS shell
        start.CreateNoWindow = true; // We don't need new window
        start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;// Any output, generated by application will be redirected back
        start.RedirectStandardError = true; // Any error in standard output will be redirected back (for example exceptions)
        using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
            {
                string stderr = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd(); // Here are the exceptions from our Python script
                string result = reader.ReadToEnd(); // Here is the result of StdOut(for example: print "test")
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: At the moment, the c# program starts python with arguments, and python saves all the data at the end of its work in one file. Now the permanent exchange isn't implemented in any way.

Comment: Python program is engaged in parsing and subsequent processing of data from a web page. She constantly checks their changes and, about once a minute, adds a new record to memory, and after accumulating a specified number of records in memory, saves them to the file. The task of the program, based on the current data, is to draw a certain output and transfer it to the c # program.

Comment: Initially, I thought to implement processing in C #, but now I realized that it is much easier to transfer several ready-made values from python. I think your answer quite does what I need :)